# How to find clear solution for iterative problem by condition $<v_k ,v_n>=0$ If $k!=n$

Tags: vector, conditional, assignment, iteration

I want to find `x[n]` by `v[n]` values without `x[n]` in solution by iterative below problem:

```
x[n] = v[n] - 
  Sum[(x[k].v[n] - \[Lambda] - (\[Lambda]*
      Sum[(x[k].v[n] - \[Lambda])/(
       x[k].x[k] - \[Lambda]), {k, 0, n - 1}])/(
     1 + \[Lambda]*Sum[1/(x[k].x[k] - \[Lambda]), {k, 0, n - 1}]))/(
    x[k].x[k] - \[Lambda]), {k, 0, n - 1}]*x[k];
```

`x[k].v[n]` is inner product. `{v[k]}` are orthogonal vectors that means, for `k!=0`, `<v[k],v[n]>=0` .
I use below cod:

```
   Clear[x, v, n, k];
n = Input["Enter n:"];
x[0] = v[0];
x[n] = v[n] - 
  Sum[(x[k].v[n] - \[Lambda] - (\[Lambda]*
      Sum[(x[k].v[n] - \[Lambda])/(
       x[k].x[k] - \[Lambda]), {k, 0, n - 1}])/(
     1 + \[Lambda]*Sum[1/(x[k].x[k] - \[Lambda]), {k, 0, n - 1}]))/(
    x[k].x[k] - \[Lambda]), {k, 0, n - 1}]*x[k];
```

How can use the condition in iterative formula?
I try using `For` and `Do` and `If`, but they didn't work.
Also Try assigning `/.v[1].v[0]->0` but they are many conditions for `n=8` .

Comment: You use the variable `k` three times, for the inner and outer sums. Please rename some of them, or your code won't run.
You're also using the index `k` outside of its scope.